# Can we restrict Column pages for a particular pages?

Tags: magento-1.9

I Want to insert a static block in this way `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerimage') ?>`  in 1 column.phtml now I want this thing to be worked only for one page say Homepage which is 1 Column not for all the other 1 column pages now can I restrict this changes only to my homepage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do this if you make changes in1column.phtml it will effect all the pages with that template rather than doing this insert the required static block in your pages content by going into CMS->Pages->Homepage-Content and paste the static block in that page's content.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your static block from `<default>` layout handler and put it on home page handler cms_index_index

goto `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout`

```
 <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="header"> <!-- your block reference -->
       <block type="cms/block" name="headerimage">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>headerimage</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        </cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but can you be more clear what should I put in cms_index_index.
Thanks in advance

Comment: But rather than doing this the above answered procedure is easy and that worked for me anyway thanks for your time

Comment: Can you please show 1column.phtm code